# os.path.isdir() not recognizing directories when path is not current directory

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

I have a list of directories (`purple`, `blue`, `red`) to be recognized in a main directory called `colors`.

When I run this script from within `colors`:

```
path_to_folders = './'
folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path_to_folders) if os.path.isdir(f)]
print(folders)
```

I get the list of folders:

```
['purple', 'blue', 'red']
```

When I set `'path_to_folders = '../colors'` and run the script from outside of the `colors` directory, the directories encompassed within it are not recognized as directories, even though they are read in as `f`.

The list of folders is empty: `[]`, but printing each `f` gives:

```
purple
blue
red
```

How can this be?

Comment: You might be aware of basic fact that 'f' is only filename and not path to file name in your later approach and it wont work if the being checked file or folder is not in CWD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.listdir()` returns just the file names, without path names, while `os.path.isdir()` requires the full path name, so you should use `os.path.join()` to prepend the path name to the file names:

```
folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path_to_folders) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path_to_folders, f))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `../` at the beginning, those folders will be treated as though they're in the CWD. No such folders in the CWD exist. Adjust your code so:

```
path_to_folders = './'
folders = [f for f in os.listdir(path_to_folders) if os.path.isdir(path_to_folders . f)]
print(folders)
```